# Building a package for another architecture

Tags: packaging, debuild

I'm trying to patch and rebuild a package (libvorbis, for what it's worth) on 64-bit Xubuntu 14.04. In the past, when I've wanted to do something like this, I've followed this formula:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
apt-get source <package>
cd <package-dir>
patch -Np1 < ../<patch>
dch -i
dpkg-source --commit
debuild -us -uc
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i <new.deb>
```

And for patching Wine in the past, it worked like a charm. For my current project, I managed to get all the way through and rebuild the packages, but when I went to install the new ones, I got:

```
dpkg: error processing package libvorbis0a:amd64 (--install):
 package libvorbis0a:amd64 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu2 cannot be configured because libvorbis0a:i386 is at a different version (1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1)
```

I was going to try uninstalling the 32-bit package, as I'm not sure I really need it, but that was going to break dependencies for a whole lot of things. How can I modify my procedure (or rerun it) to also build the 32-bit versions of the package for parallel installation? Is it possible?

**Edit:** I tried `apt-get source libvorbis:i386`, but got:

```
E: Can not find a package for architecture 'i386'
E: Unable to find a source package for libvorbis:i386
```

**Edit 2:** `apt-get source libvorbis0a:i386` appeared to work, but I just ended up with 64-bit packages again.

Comment: @Braiam When I first ran `dpkg-source --commit`, I got `'dpkg-source --commit' is not supported by the source format '1.0'`. I blindly changed debian/source/format to 2.0 and it ran. Running `debuild -us -uc -F` still just gives me the 64-bit packages.

Comment: Also tried setting debian/source/format to `3.0 (quilt)` after a little research. No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [poking around](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains) I found out that you can't do what you need to do despite multiarch goodness, at least not without installing tons of packages and/or creating a chrooted environment.

Luckily seems that buildbots and maintainers needs to do this, so there are a couple of tools that could serve this propose. I'm going to use `pbuilder`, for two reasons, it's available in Debian main repositories, ergo Ubuntu', and is automated creation of a clean ecosystem which can be updated/deleted/maintained at whim without touching your main system apart of it's flexibility. Maybe after a while I would write about the cross-toolchain.

So, start by installing the `pbuilder` and `ubuntu-dev-tools` packages and after that run `pbuilder-dist trusty i386 create` (you can also specify the target release using `--distribution trusty`, for example). Now, depending of your download and system speed this could take a while. After ending, you should be able to create any package using just the following:

```
pbuilder-dist trusty i386 libvorbis_1.3.2-1.4.dsc
```

You can change `trusty` for any other available version. It would generate a i386 version of your package.

Comment: Thanks! Worked wonderfully. Just a note: the output packages are dropped in `~/pbuilder/trusty-i386_result` (or similar).

Comment: @glibdud in  the case you used plain `pbuilder`, the packages should be in `/var/cache/pbuilder/result`.

Comment: How to do with debuilder or dpkg-build ?